# How do I use Chart.js and Bootstrap at same time? (various jQuery versions)

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, chart.js

Chart.js requires jQuery-2.1.3, but bootstrap3 requires jQuery-1.11.3

I wrote in HTML Head tags as below, but not works.

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="./dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
```

How should I include jQuery files?

Comment: I don't think Chart.js requires a specific jQuery version. For that matter, you can run Chart.js without jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

`Chart.js` does not require jQuery. While you can actually pass a jQuery object (and this can be from `jQuery` v1 or v2) in place of `ctx` while initializing the chart, you can just as easily pass in the DOM element or the 2D context.